# regex for split by single forward slash

Tags: java, regex

I have following String,

> https://www.google.com/https://www.yahoo.com/https://facebook.com/

I need to split this string as

> https://www.google.com/
>
> https://www.yahoo.com/
>
> https://facebook.com/

I tried with :

```
String urls[] = firstHalf.split("/*");
```

Is it possible?

Comment: How do you do it "in your head"? What makes you decide: "this is where I need to split"?

Comment: tried it? not that hard to see what happens... with java 9 (and 10) you can use the `jshell` BTW `*` means any number of slashes, also including none at all - so this should split between every character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this also :

```
    String test = "https://www.google.com/https://www.yahoo.com/https://facebook.com/";

    String[] urls = test.split("(?<!/)/(?!/)");

    for(String s:urls){

        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

**Output**

`https://www.google.com
 https://www.yahoo.com
 https://facebook.com`

Comment: But note this assumes that the URLs only have a domain and no path beyond that (which, however, appears to have been the case here).

Comment: yes, you are right ! that's assumption based on input in question.

Answer (score 6):

We can try splitting on the following positive lookahead:

```
(?=https?:)
```

This would break the URL string whenever a new `http` or `https` protocol appears.

```
String input = "https://www.google.com/https://www.yahoo.com/https://facebook.com/";
String[] urls = input.split("(?=https?:)");
for (String url : urls) {
    System.out.println(url);
}

https://www.google.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://facebook.com/
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you, But what if I have something like https://www.google.com/https://www.yahoo.com/https://facebook.com/youtube.com (Without https also)

Comment: Well my code would actually still work on that particular input.  But if you're saying that you could have fragments of URLs, then you would need to do more work.  But this is a pretty big departure from the question you asked.  Why are you changing requirements?

Comment: Sorry for changing it... Its dynamic string from outsource, I need to get all urls...

Comment: I don't know how to match a protocol and domain off the top of my head, so I can't easily update.  Your data source is a bad one, I think, because it is using a separator which is also part of the possible data.

Comment: Ok friend, Thank you.